# How do I visualize a three way table as a heat map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am a newbie to R and have been struggling like crazy to visualize a 3 way table as a heat map using geom_tile in R.  I can easily do this in Excel, but cannot find any examples of how to do this in R.  I have looked at using Mosaics but this is not what I want and I have found hundreds of examples of two way tables, but seems there are no examples of three way tables.

I want the output to look like this:

[image: three way table]

my data set looks like this: (its a small snapshot of 30,000 records):

```
 xxx <- structure(list(rfm_score = c(111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 121), n = c(2624L, 
    160L, 270L, 23L, 5L, 650L), rec = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
        freq = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
        "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), mon = structure(c(1L, 
        2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame")
```

It is essentially an RFM analysis of customer shopping behavior (Recency, Frequency and Monetary).  The output heat map (that I want) should be the count of customers in each RFM segments.  In the heat map I supplied, you will see there are two variables on the left (e.g. R = Recency(quintile ranges 1 to 5) and F = Frequency (quintile ranges 1 to 5)and at the top of the heat map is the M = monetary variable (quintile ranges 1 to 5).  So, for instance, the segment RFM = 555 has a count of 2511 customers.

I have tried the following code and variations of it, but just get errors

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)

cols <- rev(brewer.pal(11, 'RdYlBu'))

ols <- brewer.pal(9, 'RdYlGn')
ggplot(xxx)+ geom_tile(aes(x= mon, y = reorder(freq, desc(freq)), fill = n)) + 
  theme_change + 
  facet_grid(rec~.) + 
  # geom_text(aes(label=n)) + 
  # scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = (max(xxx$n)/2), low = "red", mid = "yellow", high = "darkgreen") + 
  # scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue") + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = cols) + 
  # scale_fill_brewer() + 
  labs(x = "monetary", y= "frequency") + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio= 0.5)
```

I have no idea how to to create this heat map in R.  Can anyone please help me..

Kind regards

Heinrich

Comment: Please provide the dataset in a usable format so we can play with it. Your code is a good start but a few things are incoherent. Faceting on both x and y variables makes no sense as it creates an individual panel for each data point. Also, you don't use your M in your ggplot call, so it won't appear in your plot. I would try `ggplot(rfm_result_final)+ 
  geom_tile(aes(moneytary_score, frequency_score, fill = count(rfm_score))) + 
  facet_grid(recency_score~.)+ ` instead. I think last version of ggplot allows you to use `count()` here, otherwise use `summarise()` from `dplyr`.

Comment: Hi Hobo Sheep.  Can you please advise how I can provide my data set in Stack overflow.  I have read several articles and loads of people complain that there is no simple way and that you need asci table converters to do this and a million other suggestions  etc.. My data set has 30,000 records so i will only supply a small sample of say 20 records. do you have any suggestions. A straight copy and paste just gives a jumble of nonsense...

Comment: That not always easy indeed, especially for such large datases. One option is to provide code that creates a data.frame containing the data. Alternatively, you can link to a google doc. I'm not an expert of SO, but these are the solutions have seen around. Did you have more success with the code I suggested?

Comment: A good way to share your data is to use `dput` , for example `dput(head(mtcars))` , then copy and paste the output into your question. You do not need to provide all rows, just a few to reproduce your problem.

Comment: ok, I have used Mike's suggestion to share the data.  Here it is:

Comment: > dput(head(rfm_result$rfm))
structure(list(customer_id = c(773229596L, 773239242L, 773245183L, 
773216648L, 773212327L, 773233187L), recency_days = c(3L, 2L, 
9L, 36L, 6L, 4L), transaction_count = c(25, 57, 4, 38, 20, 37
), amount = c(5080L, 6350L, 4090L, 4470L, 6710L, 3940L), recency_score = c(5L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L), frequency_score = c(5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
5L), monetary_score = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L), rfm_score = c(555, 
555, 334, 155, 355, 454)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") class = "data.frame")

Comment: Ok, I have finally got the code to do what I want, but the color scale gradients suck.  I have tried all sorts of tricks but cannot seem to emulate the nice color gradients in excel.

Comment: I have converted my data and it looks like this:

Comment: structure(list(rfm_score = c(111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 121), n = c(2624L, 
160L, 270L, 23L, 5L, 650L), rec = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    freq = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), mon = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: R code looks like this:

Comment: ggplot(xxx)+
  geom_tile(aes(x= mon, y = reorder(freq, desc(freq)), fill = n), width=.5, height=1) + 
facet_grid(rec~.) +
 scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = (max(xxx$n)/2), low = "red", mid = "yellow", high = "green")
# scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "yellow", high = "green") +
# scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue")
# scale_fill_gradientn(colours = (cols) +
labs(x = "monetary", y= "frequency") 
scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) 
scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) 
coord_fixed(ratio=1)
theme(legend.position = "none")

Comment: dont know how to post a snapshot of the output here in this small comment box ((((((((((((

Comment: made changes to my code:  cols <- brewer.pal(9, 'RdYlGn')

ggplot(xxx)+
  geom_tile(aes(x= mon, y = reorder(freq, desc(freq)), fill = n)) + 
  theme_change +
facet_grid(rec~.) +
#  geom_text(aes(label=n)) +
  
# scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint = (max(xxx$n)/2), low = "red", mid = "yellow", high = "darkgreen") +
# scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue") +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = cols) +
# scale_fill_brewer() +
  
labs(x = "monetary", y= "frequency") +
scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
coord_fixed(ratio= 0.5)

Comment: It would be better if you post the changes as edit into your question not in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DT` and `formattable` package to make table with conditional colour formatting:

```
library(DT)
library(formattable)


xxx <- data.frame(rfm_score = c(111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 121), 
                      n = c(2624L, 160L, 270L, 23L, 5L, 650L), 
                      rec = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                      freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
                      mon = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L)) 

xxx_dt <- formattable(
  xxx, 
  list(
    rfm_score = color_tile("pink", "light blue"),
    n = color_tile("pink", "light blue"),
    rec = color_tile("pink", "light blue"),
    freq = color_tile("pink", "light blue"),
    mon = color_tile("pink", "light blue")))

as.datatable(xxx_dt)
```

### Output:

[image: Table]